# Running PowerShell Script in CMD (with popup window)

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, popup

Hi I normally just right click and edit my scripts, then just run them through PowerShell ISE using the green arrow.

But I have a need to start /wait a script in a batch file. I want my script to run and then have the rest of the batch file to wait till the PowerShell script is closed. (Hence the start /wait)

And it works fine, but my issue is this:
it opens up fine but no matter if I choose the letters by the options or the numbers I set in the choice script it will either restart  or close out depending on the choice.

**I had nice pictures to go with this but I don't have enough rep so here is a bit of code :(

```
powershell.exe Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass


#Main Choice Script

$IP = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription '&Edit IP', 'Change IP 
Address'
$Intro= New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription '&Change Introscreen', 
'Change Introscreen'
$Gecko = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription '&Replace Gecko', 
'Change Gecko Folder'
$PCName = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription '&Host Name', 'Fix 
Host Name'
$Firewall = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription '&Firewall 
Settings', 'Fix Firewall Setting'
$Close = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription '&Close', 'Exit'



$options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]] 
($IP,$Intro,$Gecko,$PCName,$Firewall,$Close)

$title = 'IT Tool'
$message = 'What do you want to do?'
$result = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $options,-1)

switch ('$result')
{
    0 { "IP" }
    1 { "Intro" }
    2 { "Gecko" }
    3 { "PCName" }
    4 { "Firewall" }
    5 { "Close" }
    }
```

I cant seem to get the options to function right, I'm thinking:

1. CMD is too basic to open a prompt for choice window.
2. My code isn't setup to run outside ISE

** I'm fine that the cmd window is just text and not a popup, I just would like it to work.

Any help or tips would be appreciated.

Comment: There's nothing telling it to run more than once. You'll need to surround it with a `while` loop, then use `break` when you want it to end.

Comment: You should not need to use `start /wait` to run a PowerShell command or file, the next command should not run until that command has reported that it has finished. Are you wanting the PowerShell command or file to run in a completely separate console window? _as opposed to the cmd.exe window your batch file is already running within_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned you are willing to use `batch-file` I decided to post an option.

If your options are single commands per entry (or if you are willing to chain commands) you can preset the commands and use `choice` to select the option.

**Note!** Here I added some dummy commands to demonstrate how it works:

```
@echo off & cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "sel="Edit IP","Change Introscreen","Replace Gecko",Hostname,Firewall,Close"
set "opt_1=ping localhost"
set "opt_2=echo something"
set "opt_3=echo Replace command here"
set "opt_4=hostname"
set "opt_5=echo firewall command here"
set "opt_6=exit /b"
:menu
set cnt=
for %%i in (%sel%) do (
    set /a cnt+=1
    echo !cnt!^) %%~i
    set "_opt!cnt!=%%~i"
)
for /l %%c in (1,1,%cnt%) do set ch=!ch!%%c
choice /C %ch% /M "Enter Selection:"
echo You chose !_opt%errorlevel%!
!opt_%errorlevel%!
pause
set ch= & cls & goto :menu
```

Answer (score 0):

You could of course just use a plain text menu directly in your batch file, by using the built-in choice.exe utility.

```sh
@Echo Off

:Menu
ClS
Echo 1. Edit IP
Echo 2. Change Introscreen
Echo 3. Replace Gecko
Echo 4. Host Name
Echo 5. Firewall
Echo 6. Close
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C 123456 /M "What do you want to do"
GoTo Item%ERRORLEVEL%

:Item1
Echo Changing IP Address
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 2 1>NUL
GoTo :Menu

:Item2
Echo Changing Introscreen 
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 2 1>NUL
GoTo :Menu

:Item3
Echo Changing Gecko Folder
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 2 1>NUL
GoTo :Menu

:Item4
Echo Fixing Host Name
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 2 1>NUL
GoTo :Menu

:Item5
Echo Fixing Firewall Setting
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 2 1>NUL
GoTo :Menu

:Item6
Echo Exiting
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 2 1>NUL
Exit /B
```